# Nested Flexbox - outer container doesn't flex

Tags: css, flexbox

> Update : I have edited the snippet to show better what I'm trying to achieve...

I have a number of tables of data, each of variable length, on a kiosk display. I want to fill the viewport as columns then overflow to pages below ie paging down would give me next screen of data.  I thought Nested Flexbox would allow me to do this but the outer Container doesn't do what I hoped and data just flows to right - see below.  Am I just inept or should I be doing it another way? Thx!

```css
.container1 { 
  background: lightgrey;
  display: flex;
  width:300px;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  }
.container2 {
  background: orangered;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height:200px;
  width: 300px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container2 > div{
  font-size: 40px;
  width: 100px;
}  
.green {
  background: yellowgreen;
}
.blue {
  background: steelblue;
}
```

```html
My effort doesn't work ...
<div class="container1">
  <div class="container2">
    <div class="green">1a<br>1b<br>1c</div>
     <div class="blue">2a<br></div>
     <div class="green">3a<br>3b</div>
     <div class="blue">4a<br>4b<br>4c</div>  
    <div class="green">5a<br>5b</div>
     <div class="blue">6a<br></div>
     <div class="green">7a<br>7b</div>
     <div class="blue">8a<br>8b<br>8c</div>
    <div class="green">9a<br>9b<br>9c</div>
     <div class="blue">10a<br></div>
     <div class="green">11a<br>11b</div>
     <div class="blue">12a<br>12b<br>12c</div>
  </div>
</div>
I want output like this but ...
<div class="container2">
    <div class="green">1a<br>1b<br>1c</div>
     <div class="blue">2a<br></div>
     <div class="green">3a<br>3b</div>
     <div class="blue">4a<br>4b<br>4c</div>
 </div>
 <div class="container2">
    <div class="green">5a<br>5b</div>
     <div class="blue">6a<br></div>
     <div class="green">7a<br>7b</div>
     <div class="blue">8a<br>8b<br>8c</div>
</div>
 <div class="container2">
    <div class="green">9a<br>9b<br>9c</div>
     <div class="blue">10a<br>10a<br></div>
     <div class="green">11a<br>11b</div>
     <div class="blue">12a<br>12b<br>12c</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use `flex-direction: column` on the inner `container2`. You still want that to be `row`.

Setting `flex-direction: column` only establishes that the direction of children should flow from top to bottom (or reverse with `column-reverse`).

Setting `flex-wrap: wrap` on a parent with `flex-direction: column` wraps the elements on the cross axis (row in this case).

You don't even need the outer parent container, since there was only one flex child `container2`.

```css
.container2 {
  background: orangered;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.container2 > div {
  font-size: 40px;
  flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.green {
  background: yellowgreen;
}

.blue {
  background: steelblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container2">
  <div class="green">1a<br>1b<br>1c</div>
  <div class="blue">2a<br></div>
  <div class="green">3a<br>3b</div>
  <div class="blue">4a<br>4b<br>4c</div>
  <div class="green">1a<br>1b<br>1c</div>
  <div class="blue">2a<br></div>
  <div class="green">3a<br>3b</div>
  <div class="blue">4a<br>4b<br>4c</div>
  <div class="green">1a<br>1b<br>1c</div>
  <div class="blue">2a<br></div>
  <div class="green">3a<br>3b</div>
  <div class="blue">4a<br>4b<br>4c</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but sorry I didn't explain well enough - I've edited snippet to show what I want to get - I need the 2nd container (if that is the way to do it)